# CTRL-ALT-LEFT/RIGHT not working with byoby/tmux when connecting via putty

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, tmux, byobu

I have tmux (through byobu) configured to change windows on CTRL-ALT-LEFT and CTR-ALT-RIGHT. I normally connect to my machines (which run Ubuntu) from an Ubuntu machine. I now need to connect to my byobu session from a Windows machine. CTRL is just being ignored however. I can use ALT as a modifier key, but not CTR-ALT. I've tried connecting via a range of SSH programs such as putty, mobaxterm, and smarttty -- all with the same problem of not registering CTRL-ALT-LEFT/RIGHT.

I know previously I've had to play around with `~/.inputrc` to get things like CTRL-left mapping to previous-word etc, when connecting to tmux from an Ubuntu machine, but after much googling, I really don't know how to tackle this particular problem.